# Explicit examples of tensor products

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, I'm looking for sufficiently general and explicit examples of tensor products of modules over $R$.

Here are some examples that I already know:

1. If $R$ is a domain and $Q(R)$ the fraction field of $R$ then $Q(R) \otimes Q(R) \cong Q(R)$ and based on the same idea $Q(R) \otimes Q(R)/R \cong 0$.
2. If $I \subset R$ is an ideal and $M$ is a module $R/I \otimes M \cong M/IM$, and immedeatly following from this the tensor product of two quotient rings $R/I \otimes R/J \cong R/(I+J)$. This allows to compute any tensor product of finite modules over PIDs.

What other ("interesting") tensor products could be computed explicitly?

Comment: For polynomial rings we have $R[X]\otimes_R R[Y] \cong R[X,Y]$. If $S$ is an $R$-algebra, then $S\otimes_R R[X] \cong S[X]$.